# convert nsstring to cllcoordinate

Tags: iphone

i am working on a application where i am saving the coordinates of a location in database
 now i need to use these coordinates and display the location on a map. Can some one please 
suggest me how can i change the latitude & longitude stored as NSString to coordinate. I want 
to use these coordinates to display an anotation on the map.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the co-ordinates values always we got in double format.So which data types you had taken to store coordinates in database?
If store those values in the format of string(Database always accepted const char * string or pure C data types.) then u have to  type cast it into the NSString value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   CLLocationCoordinate2D anyLocation = [[CLLocationCoordinate2D alloc] init];

   anyLocation.latitude = [latText doubleValue];

   anyLocation.longitude  = [lonText doubleValue];
```

latText and lonText are strings